# Any way to launch Chrome browser without display in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, karma-runner

I'm testing my website's frontend with [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html), using google-chrome as main testing browser in Ubuntu.

The problem is that [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) occasionally fails to launch chrome browser with `Cannot start Chrome` error message.

So when I try to launch google chrome with command line in the situation, Chrome throws an `Gtk: cannot open display` error message.

Although I bump into this error sometimes even when I use my Ubuntu machine directly, I get this error more frequently when I access my machine with [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) from another window machine at my company.

Maybe I can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) as alternative testing browser, but I need exactly same testing environment as my production website will go through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Gtk: cannot open display` 
Which means it can not find display attached with device so if you have connected display you can export its address.
Generally it will be `0.0`
So your command will be like `export DISPLAY=:0.0` if doesn't work try changing `0.0` to `0` then it can find the display.
may be this link will be helpful
https://askubuntu.com/questions/47642/how-to-start-a-gui-software-on-a-remote-linux-pc-via-ssh

Answer (score 0):

Here I am suggesting you few things.
Did you installed Chrome properly?
Did you check it with any other browser? specially Firefox? And try to update Ubuntu and Chrome first, then try.